# Getting a list of usernames of Twitter followers

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am trying to get the list of the usernames that are following a certain Twitter username.
I can easily get a list of the ID's of followers by using

`http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=<ScreenName>&cursor=-1"`

but then, to get the usernames I'd need to make a call for each ID to get the username with

`http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=<userId>`

which reaches at once the 100 api call limit.

Is there a more elegant way in which I can get all usernames at once by way of php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`users/lookup`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) to look up multiple user IDs in one call, for example:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=<userId1>,<userId2>
```